# Multiple line search and replace

Tags: perl

```
my $string = "<name>
                POWERDOWN_SUPPORT
              </name>
              <bool>
                <value> true </value>
              </bool>";

    if ($string=~ s/POWERDOWN_SUPPORT<\/name><bool><value>.*?<\/value>/<false>/ims) {
    print "$string\n";
    }
```

How do I get the replacement to work?

Expected output:

```
<name>
  POWERDOWN_SUPPORT
</name>
<bool>
  <value> false </value>
</bool>
```

Comment: Looks like `xml`. Is it? If so, there's better ways than regex - like XML parsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may work:

```
s/(POWERDOWN_SUPPORT\s*?<\/name>\s*?<bool>\s*?<value>).*?(<\/value>)/$1 false $2/s
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a XML aware tool, parsing XML with regular expressions is hard and error prone.

For example, [xsh](http://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh), a wrapper around [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML):

```
open file.xml ;
my $v = //name[normalize-space(.)='POWERDOWN_SUPPORT']/following-sibling::bool/value[normalize-space(.)='true'];
set $v/text() 'false' ;
save :b ;
```

Comment: since you have mentioned xml parsing through regex is hard and error prone I tried this but getting the following error `Having no space between pattern and following word is deprecated at so.pl line 5.`

Comment: Have you installed XML::XSH2?